# Structured Streaming Aggregations return wrong values

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming

I have written a Structured Streaming aggregation that takes events from a Kafka Source, performs a simple count and writes them back to a Cassandra Database. The code looks like this:

```scala
val data = stream
  .groupBy(functions.to_date($"timestamp").as("date"), $"type".as("type"))
  .agg(functions.count("*").as("value"))

val query: StreamingQuery = data
  .writeStream
  .queryName("group-by-type")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.cassandra.CassandraSinkProvider")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
  .option("checkpointLocation", config.getString("checkpointLocation") + "/" + "group-by-type")
  .option("keyspace", "analytics")
  .option("table", "aggregations")
  .option("partitionKeyColumns", "project,type")
  .option("clusteringKeyColumns", "date")
  .start()
```

The problem is that the count is just over every single batch. So I will see counts dropping in Cassandra. The counts should never drop over a day, how can I achieve that?

Edit:
I have tried using window aggregations too, same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error in this case wasn't actually in my query or in Spark.
To figure out where the problem is I used the console sink and that one did not show the problem.

The problem was in my Cassandra sink which looked like this:

```
class CassandraSink(sqlContext: SQLContext, keyspace: String, table: String) extends Sink {
  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
    data.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).cassandraFormat(table, keyspace).save()
  }
}
```

It uses the Datastax Spark Cassandra connector to write data frames.

The problem is that the variable `data` contains a streaming DataSet. In the ConsoleSink that's provided by Spark the DataSet gets copied into a static DataSet before writing. So I've changed it and now it works. The finished version looks like this:

```
class CassandraSink(sqlContext: SQLContext, keyspace: String, table: String) extends Sink {
  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
    val ds = data.sparkSession.createDataFrame(
      data.sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data.collect()),
      data.schema
    )
    ds.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).cassandraFormat(table, keyspace).save()
  }
}
```